# MySQL query having multiple count conditions grouped by same column

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I am new to MySQL queries with group by

I have these tables:

- **user** that has columns: *`userid`, `position`, `dept_id`, `status`*
- **department** that has columns: *`dept_id`, `name`*

I want a query to count all users whose position is an ojt, subcon,
whose status is resigned on all departments

so I have a table looking like this:

```
SEDC dept:
ojt users count: 13
subcon users count: 32
resigned users count: 2


HR dept:
ojt users count: 2
subcon users count: 3
resigned users count: 1

Finance dept:
ojt users count: 4
subcon users count: 6
resigned users count: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d.dept_id,u.position,count(userid) AS count
FROM user u INNER JOIN department d
ON u.dept_id = d.dept.id AND u.status = 'resigned'
GROUP BY d.dept_id,u.position
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select a.nam,case when position='ojt' then acount else o end as ojtuser
case when position='subcon' then acount else o end as subconuser
regincount 
  from department a
join(
select dept_id,Position,Count(*) acount from user
group by Dept_id,Position)b on a.dept_id=b.dept_id
join(
select dept_id,Count(*) regincount from user status=resigned
group by dept_id)c on a.dept_id=c.dept_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this query and it works for me:

```
SELECT d.departmentname dept, 
       sum(m.position = "subcon") subcon,   
       sum(m.position = "ojt") ojt,     
       sum(m.status = 'h') hr_intra
from user m
right join department d
on m.department_id = d.id
group by d.id
```